# how java SocketServer works?

Tags: java

I am new to java, I can't understand the while loop part of void go() method.The accept() method waits for the client request to connect to the server, so why the other statements like Print writer etc, are not executed?

Do the other statments wait in the while loop for the accept() methods to run??

```
 import java.io.*;
  import java.net.*;
 import java.util.*;


 public class VerySimpleChatServer
 {
ArrayList clientOutputStreams;

public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
    BufferedReader reader;
    Socket sock;

    public ClientHandler(Socket clientSOcket) {
        try {
            sock = clientSOcket;
            InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);

        } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    public void run() {
        String message;
        try {
            while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("read " + message);
                tellEveryone(message);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new VerySimpleChatServer().go();
}

public void go() {
    clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList();
    try {
        ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(5000);
        while(true) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSock.accept();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientOutputStreams.add(writer);

            Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
            t.start();
            System.out.println("got a connection");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
}

public void tellEveryone(String message) {
    Iterator it = clientOutputStreams.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        try {
            PrintWriter writer = (PrintWriter) it.next();
            writer.println(message);
            writer.flush();
        } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
}
```

No clue, please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That accept method does not just *wait*.

It **blocks**. Execution only continues when that method returns! The "flow of execution" stops there - the following statements are irrelevant until that method call returns.

That is all there is to this.

Comment: I have one more problem, after the connection is made do the readLine() method continuously checks for the message in the socket to read?or how the server get the message from the client again and again?

Comment: By reading from the reader?  My suggestion : don't go trial and error. Get a complete tutorial or book and follow that.

Comment: Got it!! I'm doing the same